# How to capture values in loadrunner

Tags: loadrunner

I enter a transaction using loadrunner and a transaction number get's generated, now can i store that value in a file? Also, when used controller to simulate 10 users i want the 10 transaction numbers to stored as well. please advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

These timing records (transactions) are automatically collected as part of the controller efforts.  You do not need to store them in a file.   If your transaction names are getting truncated then you need to look at their length, whether they have spaces or special characters that are likely the root of your issue.

Comment: So, where can i see them in controller? could you please elaborate?

Comment: All transactions (set with lr_[start|end]_transaction() who up in the run tab of the console.   You also observe all of the data in the Analysis at the end of the test.

Answer (score 0):

VuGen is just used for recording the script. The same script would be simulated in Controller.

Once the Test is over, you can see your results in Analysis.